# Mongoid embeddable comments and user info that can change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, database-design, mongoid

I have an List document with embedded Comments.  Along with the user's comment in the view, I'd like to display their screen name and profile picture.  The profile picture could change and so could the screen name.

I'm trying to determine what the best practice is here for design.  To best leverage Mongo, it seems like like the embedded Comment should look like the following:

Comment Model

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :user_id
  field :username
  field :profile_pic_url
  field :content
  field :created_at, type: Date
  embedded_in :list, :inverse_of => :comments
end
```

The risk though is that comment data (user's screen name and profile pic) becomes stale if the user changes them unless there's a after_save filter on the User model for instance that looks to update all instances in comments.

Any guidance on proper design?  I could make it so that comments are not embedded and make it so that a user has many comments and a list has many comments, but I'm trying to play to Mongo's strengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application, it's access patterns, scaling, and performance requirements trump backend issues.  With SQL, normalization and linking/referencing is pretty much your only choice, but with MongoDB, you can embed.

MongoDB provides the flexibility to match schema to the needs of your application, you can choose normalization/linking/referencing or denormalizing/embedding as needed, and Mongoid makes it easy to choose.

(a) Normalization reduces redundancy, following the good principle of Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY).
(b) Denormalization introduces redundancy, following common practices such as caching or memoizing for performance.

In general based on the needs of your application:

High consistency required - yes: normalize / link, no: denormalize / embed

High read performance required - yes: denormalize / embed, no: normalize / link

High write performance required - yes: normalize / link, no: denormalize / embed

High scaling required - yes: normalize / link, no: denormalize / embed

Relationships:

one-to-one - yes: denormalize / embed, no: ...

one-to-many - yes: denormalize / embed, no: ...

many-to-many - yes: normalize / link, no: ...

There are various techniques for handling consistency, ex., background or nightly process for eventual consistency, look-aside cache for immediate consistency, etc.

The bad news is that there's no formula that requires no thought.  The good news is that MongoDB has the flexibility to match your application.  10gen offers talks on Schema Design.

Comment: I went with storing both the user's screen name and image as part of the comments as that approach best matched the performance profile I was hoping to achieve by embedding the comments in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I would reference a user instead of putting each field in each comment.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :user_id
  field :username
  field :profile_pic_url
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :content
  belongs_to :user
  embedded_in :list, :inverse_of => :comments
end
```

You can find documentation for the has_many relation at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many

I also went ahead and used the timestamps extra and removed the created_at field which is documented at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#timestamps.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, this seems to be the right approach for the job!

Comment: One thing I noticed.  My expectation was that I could access the user model from comment.  Since comment is embedded in list, Mongoid tells me that I would need to store an extra foreign key in the root document (presumably the List document).  Here what I was trying to do in my view:  - @comments.each do |c|
  %a.pull-left
    = image_tag c.user.profile.image :class => 'media-object'
  .media-body
    %h4.media-heading= c.username
    = c.content